# Check if an array contains an invalid value and return false?

Tags: c#

This is probably very simple but I guess I haven't had enough of coffee yet.

I have an array with four values and I want to check if any of them is invalid and then set a boolean value to false, else to true.

```
bool validDecoding = false;
foreach (string decodedValue in arrayOfvalues)
{
    if (decodedValue.Contains("invalid") || decodedValue.Contains("length") || decodedValue.Contains("bad"))
    {
        validDecoding = false;
    }
    else
    {
        validDecoding = true;
    }
}
```

But if the last does not contain invalid, length or bad then validDecoding is set to true but I want it to be false if one or more values are invalid.

Please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Include `System.Linq` namespace and you can do following:

```
validDecoding = !arrayOfvalues.Any(
    value => value.Contains("invalid") || value.Contains("length") || value.Contains("bad"));
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was writing :)

Comment: It would look prettier with line breaks, but I don't edit other people's code. :)

Comment: It will look even prettier if you change mulitiple "||" to single HashSet<string>.Contains().

Answer (score 1):

Set valid to true at first, then set it to false in your loop if it's invalid.

```
bool validDecoding = true;
foreach (string decodedValue in arrayOfvalues)
{
    if (decodedValue.Contains("invalid") || decodedValue.Contains("length") || decodedValue.Contains("bad"))
    {
        validDecoding = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

That way it's never set back to true! (you need more coffee ;-) )

Comment: You should also break out of the foreach as soon as your criteria is met to keep from processing more records than you have to.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool validDecoding = false;
foreach (string decodedValue in arrayOfvalues)
{
    if (!decodedValue.Contains("invalid") && !decodedValue.Contains("length") && !decodedValue.Contains("bad"))
    {
        validDecoding = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your validDecoding to 'true' initially, and only reset to false if it breaks.

```
bool validDecoding = true;
foreach (string decodedValue in arrayOfvalues)
{
    if (decodedValue.Contains("invalid") || decodedValue.Contains("length") || decodedValue.Contains("bad"))
    {
        validDecoding = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Do Nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Andrew's answer.  If you don't have Linq available, try this option:

```
// Note: Name boolean variables like they are a question
bool isValidDecoding = true;

foreach (string decodedValue in arrayOfvalues)
{
    isValidDecoding &= !decodedValue.Contains("invalid")
        && !decodedValue.Contains("length")
        && !decodedValue.Contains("bad");
}
```

I particularly like this option when your tests contain logging, and you want to find all failures before termination.

I'd be wary of `decodedValue.Contains("length")` though.  Maybe it works in your scenario, but it might give false negatives for other cases, and definitely makes your code less clear.  You should double check that there isn't a more unique/indicative value that ensures that you have a bad decoding for those cases.